# Dockerfile Reference ARG for Download in URL

Tags: dockerfile

I'm trying to build a simple container image that has a set of tools installed for me to use when required. One of the tools I'm looking at including in the image is cfssl.

The binary for cfssl is located on github and I would like to reference a specific version using an arg. When I try to do this, the argument is not "replaced" when building out the image and instead taken literally which results in a failed build due to a failed wget command.

The code from the dockerfile that I'm trying to get working is below:

```
ARG CFSSL_VERSION=1.6.4
RUN wget https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/releases/download/v${CFSSL_VERSION}/cfssl_${CFSSL_VERSION}_linux_amd64 -O cfssl \
    && chmod +x cfssl \
    && mv cfssl /usr/bin
```

So far, I have hard coded the version into the URL which is working, but ideally I'd like to add an argument that allows me to change the version of cfssl when required.

Any ideas on how to get this working?